# How do I use the dual table for XML generation?

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

Below is a sample output. I want to generate the following output using `plsqlxml`, but how can I get the data from dual table. Is it possible?

```
<Users>
<User>
<UserDescription i:nil="true"/>
<UserTypeCD>DL</DealUserTypeCD>
<Employee>
<EmailAddress i:nil="true"/>
<EmployeeNr i:nil="true"/>
</Employee>
</User>
<User>
<UserDescription i:nil="true"/>
<UserTypeCD>DC</UserTypeCD>
<Employee>
<EmailAddress i:nil="true"/>
<EmployeeNr i:nil="true"/>
</Employee>
```

I am passing `usertypecode` hardcoded, so I need the dual table.

Comment: I have no idea what `plsqlxml` is supposed to be? And what is the expected output based on that XML document?

Comment: XML generation through oracle.I need to generate above xml based on the hardcoded values.its possiable?

Comment: Why do you need `dual` for hard-coded values?  You can use a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a XML documnet by 2 ways.

**1) Using constructor of XMLTYPE**

```
DECLARE
   l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_refcursor FOR SELECT department_id
                             , department_name
                          FROM departments
                         WHERE department_id IN (10,20);

   l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_refcursor);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;
/
```

2) Using **DBMS_XMLGEN package**. DBMS_XMLGEN built-in is similar to the XMLTYPE constructor, but accepts a query directly:

```
DECLARE
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    l_xmltype := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT department_id
                                              , department_name
                                           FROM departments
                                          WHERE department_id IN (10,20)'
                                       );

    dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;
/
```